# R - comparing simple regression models that were run on several DVs

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

Say you have the following code in R:

```
model1 <- lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3) ~ IV1 + IV2, data)
```

This code should perform separate regressions of `IV1 + IV2` on `DV1`, then of `IV1 + IV2` on `DV2` and lastly, of `IV1 + IV2` on `DV3`.

Say that we also have a model which includes interaction between IV1 and IV2:

```
model2 <- lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3) ~ IV1 * IV2, data)
```

To test if there is an interaction, I would usually use:

```
anova(model1, model2)
```

However, this returns only one p-value, whereas I was expecting three p-values - one for `DV1`, one for `DV2` and one for `DV3`. How can I achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: I guess you need `Map(anova, model1, model2)`

Comment: If you do something like this, `Map` would work `model1n <- lapply(c('mpg', 'disp'), function(x) lm(reformulate(response = x, 'cyl + am'), data = mtcars));
model2n <- lapply(c('mpg', 'disp'), function(x) lm(reformulate(response = x, 'cyl * am'), data = mtcars));
Map(anova, model1n, model2n)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, this works! I suggest adding it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` if it is done individually

```
model1n <- lapply(c('mpg', 'disp'), function(x) 
    lm(reformulate(response = x, 'cyl + am'), data = mtcars))
model2n <- lapply(c('mpg', 'disp'), function(x) 
     lm(reformulate(response = x, 'cyl * am'), data = mtcars))
Map(anova, model1n, model2n)
```